# What is the randomness of Apple generated passwords?

Tags: security, password

Today I was reading about an issue with the Kaspersky Password generator (https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1412411435842519049.html).  They had an issue where the seed used was the epoch time in seconds which is a very insecure method.  I was curious about the strength of the strong passwords generated by Apple. I haven't been able to find any details on the process Apple uses to generate their passwords.  However, I did find something that really bothers me when I looked at my saved passwords.  I sorted my saved passwords alphabetically and found that the exact same generated password was used on three completely different websites.  The passwords are 18 characters long so this is not random chance.  The passwords were created in different years on different times of day.  This brings up a couple of questions:

-First, does anyone else see this issue?

-Does Apple have any info on the password generation process?

Comment: I assume it uses https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/security/seca0c73a75b/web but I don't know if that is correct.

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally selected to use an existing password when creating the new login?

Answer (score 1):

Apple’s documentation on this topic is in the Apple Platform Security guide. It explains about the intended generation but not how they are generated.

> By default, passwords generated by iOS and iPadOS are 20 characters long. They contain one digit, one uppercase character, two hyphens and 16 lowercase characters. These generated passwords are strong, containing 71 bits of entropy.

https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secc84c811c4/1/web/1

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned 18 characters in my question because it looks like the hyphens are fixed.